# Why constructor is not executed while cloning

Tags: java

```
Animal animal = new Animal(101);              //Constructor is executed.

Animal clone=(Animal)animal.clone()     //Constructor is not executed. Why ?
```

Comment: The Java specification says it so. I recommend Joshua Bloch's Effective Java book, for more info.

Comment: Cloning does not call the constructor for you. If you want to run a constructor, call a constructor explicitly.

Comment: Why do you think it should call constructor?

Comment: A clone is not created using a constructor. Simply creates new instance and copies the values of the fields. (unless you override the clone method to do it in another way)

Comment: @Sergey Pauk Yes it does.

Comment: @Sergey Pauk Implement `Cloneable` and `CloneNotSupportedException` won't be thrown.

Comment: Well I was thinking cloning also creates an object so Should call constructor.@RohitJain

Comment: New instance is created without calling constructor ? @Bubletan       Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SergeyPauk's comment is incorrect and bad advice. Never call the object's constructor from a `clone` method. The standard way to implement `clone` is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052340/what-is-wrong-with-this-clone/1053227#1053227

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default implementation of the `clone()` method given in the `Object` class does not call any kind of constructor.

It makes a "shallow copy" of object,  because it creates copy of Object by creating new instance and then copying content by assignment, which means **if your Class contains a mutable field, then both original object and clone will refer to same internal object**.

Try to have a look at [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.it/2013/09/how-clone-method-works-in-java.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor isn't called because you are calling the clone() method. 
Based on the way how the clone method is implemented, it does not need to call the constructor.

One way to involve the constructor would be by implementing the clone method with a copy constructor, like so:

```
public class A implements Cloneable{

private int example;

public A(){
//this is the default constructor, normally not visible and normally not needed, 
//but needed in this case because you supply another constructor
}

public A(A other){
    this.example = other.example;
}

//You may specify a stronger type as return type
public A clone(){
    return new A(this);
}

}
```

Now, every time you call the clone method, the copy constructor (the one with the A-parameter) is called.

regards
me

Comment: Your class must implement `Clonable`, or a `CloneNotSupported` will be thrown.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot it because I did not write it in an IDE;)
I added it now and upvoted your comment ;)

Comment: I think you should modify your answer, because your example is not correct. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052340/what-is-wrong-with-this-clone/1053227#1053227).

Comment: Do not call the constructor, rather call `super.clone()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052340/what-is-wrong-with-this-clone/1053227#1053227